# Tech noir/cyber noir detective novel from 80s/90s

Tags: story-identification, novel, cyberpunk

I remember that the detective had an apartment that could change interior colors. I also remember one character, who was a boss of some sort that had bodyguards that were, maybe, genetically modified to be super beefy and could flick off bullets.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you read this?  Was it in English?  Do you recall any details of the book?  (Paperback vs. hardcover, length, cover art...)

Comment: Was it set in the Middle East?

Comment: @LAK You thinking of *When Gravity Fails* too?  The Stone and the Stone Who Speaks (Bey's bodyguards) could fit, although I don't remember either of them being shot at, and Audran's apartment isn't fancy enough to change colours.

Comment: @DavidW Yes, that was my initial thought, but I don't remember many of the details.

Comment: Note that proposed duplicate target is already the target for another closed question.

Comment: Thanks to DavidW for flagging this for closure again. I messed up reopening it when I should've edited its dupe target instead, and found that I was unable to close it again, or even flag it for closure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that is ["Only Forward"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/920395.Only_Forward) by Michael Marshall Smith.

> Stark lives in Colour, a neighbourhood whose inhabitants like to be co-ordinated with their surroundings – a neighbourhood where spangly purple trousers are admired by the walls of buildings as you pass them. Close by is Sound, where you mustn’t make any, apart from one designated hour a day when you can scream your lungs raw. Then there’s Red – get off at F**k Station Zero if you want to see a tactical nuclear battle recreated as a sales demonstration.
>
> Stark has friends in Red, which is just as well because Something is about to happen. And when a Something happens it’s no good chanting ‘Duck and cover’ while cowering in a corner, because a Something is always from the past, Stark’s past, and it won’t go away until you face it full on.

Comment: Thanks lolrus! This is it!